# remove and reset button for item list

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to create a remove selected item and reset button which removes an item from a list box and reduces the cost of that item in a label. However, The clear button resets the cost and item list text but when clicking a button to add the item again it adds it once into the textbox but brings back the original cost as well as adding the new cost. The Remove selected item button removes the item but not the amount of the cost of that item. What am i doing wrong? Apologies for the bad English.[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwfS8.png)

```
Option Strict On
Public Class sandwichInterface
Dim DecTotal As Decimal

    Private Sub btnCiabatta_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCiabatta.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Add("1 Ciabatta £1.50")
    ListBox1.Text = ListBox1.Text + ("1 Ciabatta £1.50") + Chr(13)
    DecTotal = DecTotal + CDbl(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right("1 Ciabatta £1.50", 4))
    lblTotal.Text = "Total £" + Format(DecTotal, "###.00")
End Sub


Private Sub btnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
    If ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text = "1 Ciabatta £1.50" Then DecTotal = DecTotal - CDbl(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right("1 Ciabatta £1.50", 4))
    lblTotal.Text = "Total £" + Format(DecTotal, "###.00")
End Sub 

Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    If DecTotal = lblTotal.Text Then lblTotal.Text = "£0.00"

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Did you have a question?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  You should also put `Option Strict On` at the top of your code file.

Comment: Re: edit - the code posted wont even compile now.  Using Option Strict you cannot compare numbers to strings: `If DecTotal = lblTotal.Text`.  Please read [Ask] and take the[Tour]

Answer (score 0):

Urgh, it pains me to even read this code but here goes!

Delete this from the add:

```
ListBox1.Text = ListBox1.Text + ("1 Ciabatta £1.50") + Chr(13)
```

Swap these 2 lines round, you can't check the value of the selected item after you removed it.:

```
ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
If ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text = "1 Ciabatta £1.50" Then DecTotal = DecTotal - CDbl(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right("1 Ciabatta £1.50", 4))
```

By this:

```
If DecTotal = lblTotal.Text Then lblTotal.Text = "£0.00"
```

I can only guess you mean

```
DecTotal = 0
lblTotal.Text = "£0.00"
```

I also have no idea why you would do this:

```
If ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text = "1 Ciabatta £1.50" Then DecTotal = DecTotal - CDbl(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right("1 Ciabatta £1.50", 4))
```

Instead of:

```
If ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text = "1 Ciabatta £1.50" Then DecTotal = DecTotal - 1.50
```

Even if the latter is still pretty awful!

Your whole approach to this is not nice though, passing around money as part of a string and using `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right` and `Cdbl` to convert it to a float is pretty awful practice to say the least.

Comment: When you wondered about the
If ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text =
I had a terrible vision of a whole list of If statements, not in a loop, but one for each food item.
I just hope this is a student project. Every time there is a price change, someone will have to take the whole thing apart and put it back together.

Comment: I am new to programming, this is a student project and my first time using VB. So feedback is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This code is not meant to paste into your project but to show you how some things could be done. I created a simple class to add objects to the list box. The Button2.Click shows how you could add items to your list box. You would add them one by one probably from Button events. Button 2 also shows how to get a total for the price. The $ before the string means that it is an interpolated string that can include variables. The :c after Total formats Total to local currency.
The button3.click shows how to remove an item from the list and adjust the total.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        ListBox3.Items.Clear()

        With ListBox3.Items
            .Add(New FoodItem("Ciabatta", 1.5))
            .Add(New FoodItem("Good Bread", 0.5))
            .Add(New FoodItem("Great Bread", 2.0))
        End With
        For Each item As FoodItem In ListBox3.Items
            Total += item.Price
        Next
        lblTotal.Text = $"{Total:c}"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim SelectedFoodItem As FoodItem = DirectCast(ListBox3.SelectedItem, FoodItem)
        Dim d As Double = SelectedFoodItem.Price
        ListBox3.Items.Remove(ListBox3.SelectedItem)
        Total -= d
        lblTotal.Text = $"{Total:c}"
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class FoodItem
    Public Sub New()
        'Default
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(objFoodName As String, dblPrice As Double)
        FoodName = objFoodName
        Price = dblPrice
    End Sub

    Private _FoodName As String
    Public Property FoodName As String
        Get
            Return _FoodName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _FoodName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Price As Double
    Public Property Price As Double
        Get
            Return _Price
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            _Price = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{_FoodName}  {_Price:c}"
    End Function

End Class
```